# D3: Uncaught ReferenceError: stream_layers is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I was using **nvd3.js** to create a simple stacked bar chart as described [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html)

I added the code mentioned in the link in an **angular directive** as follows:

```
app.directive('stackBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            nv.addGraph(function() {
                var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
                            /*.transitionDuration(350)*/
                            .reduceXTicks(true)   //If 'false', every single x-axis tick label will be rendered.
                            /*.rotateLabels(0)    */  //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
                            .showControls(true)   //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode.
                            .groupSpacing(0.1)    //Distance between each group of bars.

                chart.xAxis
                            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

                chart.yAxis
                            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

                d3.select(element[0])
                            .datum(exampleData())
                            .call(chart);

                nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
                return chart;
            });

            //Generate some nice data.
            function exampleData() {
                return stream_layers(3,10+Math.random()*100,.1).map(function(data, i) {
                        return {
                            key: 'Stream #' + i,
                            values: data
                        };
                });
            }
        }
    }   
});
```

Here's my **HTML:**

```
<td class="centered" colspan="5">
      <div stack-bar>

      </div>
</td>
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stream_layers is not defined
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Also, 'transitonDuration' was also not working so I commented it out. I initially thought, this maybe some problem related to the version of d3, but I am using the latest version and still the problem persists.

**EDIT:**

Huang Feng's answer helped me get rid of the error. But instead of getting any chart I am getting a lot of text. Here's a **screenshot:**

[image]

Any idea why?

Also, the directive is in an **ng-repeat**, and thats why there are multiple rows as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you don't define the stream_layers function, and it's also not a function in nvd3 lib.
It's defined here:

http://nvd3.org/assets/js/data/stream_layers.js

If you want to use it, you should include this lib in the html like:

```
<script src="../stream_layers.js"></script>
```

If you want a detail example, here is one for your reference:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967

Comment: Is this function available somewhere? Alternatively, isn't there a simple example for the stacked bar chart?

Comment: It's only a data generator. I have updated the answer, you can find the definition of the stream_layer function there.

Comment: The error got fixed, but I am getting a lot of text on the screen and no chart. Uploading the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @huang feng, I edited the question, can you please have a look?

Comment: @huang feng, this is the entire code excluding the generator and the HTML where I have included the libraries.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the directive you used, i just know something about d3 and nvd3, i'll try to look at the code and hope i can help on this.

Comment: I create a plunk for you, you didn't used d3.select in a correct way, please see my plnkr for detail http://plnkr.co/edit/7YP0gL8mlWLBtx7AqIGS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar output (and errors), and there were **3** things needed to fix this:

#### 1. Add `stream_layers.js` to path

As mentioned by [huan feng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959152/3854235), you need to include the `stream_layers.js` function to generate fake data for the example. I downloaded the source code from [nvd3.org](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/zipball/master), and the `stream_layers.js` file was located in `novus-nvd3-8ceb270/test/stream_layers.js` (you'll most likely need to update *at least* that first part of your path based on the latest shortened git hash.

#### 2. Replace `transitionDuration` with `duration`

Another issue is that the API has changed for NVD3. After inspecting the source code (line 456 in `novus-nvd3-8ceb270/src/models/multiBarChart.js`), the `transitionDuration` method has been replaced with just `duration`. Here is a snippet from your code above with the duration option corrected:

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
  .duration(350)
  .reduceXTicks(true)   //If 'false', every single x-axis tick label will be rendered.
  /*.rotateLabels(0)    */  //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
  .showControls(true)   //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode.
  .groupSpacing(0.1)    //Distance between each group of bars.
```

#### 3. Create an SVG

Lastly, your screen shot is only showing text. I think the reason for this is because you were trying to append your chart to a div when it needs to be appended to an SVG element. One way of correcting this is by appending an svg to element[0], and then selecting that svg to use with your vizualization:

```
var svg = d3.select(element[0])
  .append('svg')
  .attr('id', 'my-bar-chart-svg')

d3.select('#my-bar-chart-svg')
   .datum(exampleData())
   .call(chart);
```

If you're still not seeing anything, you might need to fiddle with the width and height of the SVG element you created to append your chart to. Here's one quick hack for testing:

```
var svg = d3.select(element[0])
  .append('svg')
  .attr('id', 'my-bar-chart-svg')
  .attr('width', 800)
  .attr('height', 400)

d3.select('#my-bar-chart-svg')
   .datum(exampleData())
   .call(chart);
```